# Encoding problem using Apache HTTP client to download Chinese website

Tags: java, apache, encoding, rss, httpclient

I have an encoding issue downloading a Chinese RSS url http://finance.qq.com/stock/ggjj/rss_ggjj.xml

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try {
        String url = "http://finance.qq.com/stock/ggjj/rss_ggjj.xml";
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            response.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

The output contains bad encoded characters:

> ... �ㄨ����搴�锛�涓��ㄤ�娉煎��������姘� ...

Comment: who says they are bad encoded? you may very well be using the wrong encoding.

Comment: [1] If I enter your URL in Firefox I get this error: _`"XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://finance.qq.com/stock/ggjj/rss_ggjj.xml Line Number 26, Column 206: <description>鑵捐璇..."`_. [2] I tried several other web sites with pages in Chinese and your code worked fine. [3] With Java 11 you don't need to use Apache code. Instead you could try the [HTTP Client and WebSocket APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html).

Comment: The site finance.qq.com/stock/ggjj/rss_ggjj.xml is sending in the header Content-Type: text/xml; charset=GB2312 then EntityUtils.toString will use GB2312 to encode bytes to String. A workaround is to encode bytes directly using charset=UTf-8.